# Error 400 by using Retrofit Android Studio using API Net Core

Tags: java, android-studio, asp.net-core, retrofit

I'm trying to do a POST request using Retrofit in Android Studio Java but the response says "Error 400", I create the API too so, I don't know what's wrong, the API was created in NET core this is my application code:

```
  private void senddata(String nombre,String edad){
    OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder=new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.24.1.29/sicegipruebas4/api/")
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    KidInterface inter=retrofit.create(KidInterface.class);
    try{
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        obj.put("id",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        obj.put("name", nombre);
        obj.put("edad",edad);
        Call<Kid> call=inter.createPost(obj.toString());
        call.enqueue(this);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My interface:

```
public interface KidInterface {
  @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8"})
  @POST("kids")
  Call<Kid> createPost(@Body String kid); 
 }
```

And my model:

```
public class Kid {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("edad")
private String edad;

public Kid(String id,String name,String edad){
  this.id=id;
  this.name=name;
  this.edad=edad;
}
```

And the API code:

```
 public class Kids
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String edad { get; set; }

}
```

Context API:

```
public class AppNNADBContext:DbContext
{
    public AppNNADBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Kids> Kids { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Kids>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result in log cat:

[result post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCnrq.png)

[Json warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHzUt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to convert object to json before posting. Since you already have Kids model. and added GsonConverterFactory it will automatically take care of serialization and deserialization of objects. You can use this model in @Body.

```
public interface KidInterface {
  @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8"})
  @POST("kids")
  Call<Kid> createPost(@Body Kid kid); 
}
```

to post

```
Kid kid=new Kid();
kid.id=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
kid.name=nombre;
kid.edad=edad;

Call<Kid> call=inter.createPost(kid);
```